# avconv - Automatically change orientation based on metadata

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, avconv

I am running a server application that accepts video uploads from an iOS app. The app uploads a .mov to the server and the server converts it to .mp4 (this is for future Android compatibility). The problem is that the .mov format uses a rotation flag in the metadata that doesn't work very well with the conversion and videos frequently end up in the wrong orientation. The command I'm using,

```
avconv -i iosvideo.mov -c:v libx264 -b:v 1250k -vf scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480,transpose=1 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -t 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

seems to only rotate a fixed amount. How would I go about having avconv read the rotation flag from the .mov and rotate the video stream accordingly?

Comment: I think you probably want to think of it as a two-step thing, first find some way to read the rotation metadata (using e.g. ffprobe or exiftool or so), then use that to set the correct rotate/transpose/vflip/hflip parameters in your ffmpeg commandline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download or compile](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) a recent build of `ffmpeg`. It will automatically rotate your video, so your command could look like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -vf scale=-2:480 -t 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 192k \
-movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- Disable this behavior with `-noautorotate`.
- For `scale`, you can use `-2` instead of `trunc(oh*a/2)*2`.
- [Use `-crf` instead of `-b:v`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). If you must target a specific output file size, then use `-b:v`, but with two passes; not one. Default is `-crf 23`.
- `libvo_aacenc` is a poor encoder. Consider using an alternative [AAC encoder](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) if possible.
- You will probably want `-movflags +faststart` so the video may begin playing back before it is completely downloaded by the client.
- I'm not sure if any of this info will apply to `avconv`; I don't use that.
- Next time ask at Super User; your question is offtopic here since it is not programming related. Stack Overflow is not a general computing help resource.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and more. Thank you